# How to refresh other view controllers based on a action from base view

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

On my base view controller I have a map with the user's pinned location on it, which is then stored into `NSUserdefaults`. I also have a delete option where the user can delete his/her pinned annotation. The app is run by a tab controller so the first tab is the user's pinned location and the second tab is a detail view of the pinned location. However, when I remove the annotation from the `first view controller`, the old location still stays on the `detailed view controller`.

Is there anyway I can refresh/reload the detail view controller based on the actions of the base VC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSNotifications` for this.

In your first view controller, you actually want to receive the notification, not set up the notification.

**Second View Controller**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "resetData:", name: "reloadData", object: nil);
```

and then have a method for your selector...

```
func resetData(notification:NSNotification) {
    smallMapView.removeAnnotations(smallMapView.annotations);
    smallMapView.showsUserLocation = true;
    var location = locationManager.location;
    var latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    var longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.001;
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.001;

    var span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta);
    var overallLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(overallLoc, span);
    self.smallMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
```

This will reset the pin and center in your detail map on the user's current location (You can change that functionality if you need to).

**First View Controller**

I'm assuming you used a `NSAlertView` here...

```
@IBAction func trashButtonSelected(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Remove from NSDefaults
    // Show alertview
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you Sure?", message: "Do you wish to delete your pinned Location?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet);
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (Action) in
        // Cancel
    }
    let deleteButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Destructive) { (Action) in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("pinnedLocation");
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadData", object: nil);
        self.map.removeAnnotations(self.map.annotations);
        self.pinLocationButton.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This should do the job :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to achieve this.

Basically the `NSNotificationCenter` keeps a reference to any object that is registered as an observer. With that reference, it also keeps track of what kind of notifications that object wants. When an object posts a notification, the center delivers it to each registered observer by sending the observer a message with that selector.

Suppose you have two View Controller

1. First View Controller
2. Second View Controller

Now you want to perform some action in First View Controller based on some action in Second View Controller.Then in FirstViewController you just register this view controller as an observer and implement the method where you want to handle  the notification.From SecondViewController you have to send the notification.

### FirstViewController.m

In first view controller you have to register an observer like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performAction) name:@"reload_data" object:nil];
}
```

This will be called when you will get some notification from SecondViewController.

```
- (void)performAction {
    NSLog(@"Do whatever you want to do");
}
```

### SecondViewController.m

From here I am sending the notification from SeconViewController.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload_data" object:self];
```

}

Comment: Is there a swift version of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the conical problem of Object Oriented programming, how to inform objects that some event has occurred?

One good article on the subject is [When to use Delegation, Notification, or Observation in iOS](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/). (As you would expect, each of these three patterns have their pros and cons.) You could also "roll your own" solution by implementing some variation of the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html). There are also several "off-shelf" solutions as well like ReactiveCocoa and RxSwift (both on github and available through cocoapods).

I get the impression that you are kind of new to programming. As such, I suggest you implement the Notification Center solution shown in other answers here, but then re-impliment the solution using Key Value Observing, and then implement it again using Delegation. That way you will get the sense of all of these important patterns and have a good idea about which is best in your particular situation. If you feel adventurous, you can also investigate one of the Reactive solutions... the learning curve is higher, but they are powerful tools that can be used in many disparate situations.

Comment: Thanks for the article!